# How to enable app sandbox in iOS keyboard extention?

Tags: ios, ios-keyboard-extension

I am building a new iOS app - keyboard extention which include network connection.
While testing in on simulator I was able to use network(POST request) but when trying to run it on my iPhone 13 I am getting this:
*error: A server with the specified hostname could not be found.: A server with the specified hostname could not be found.*

it feels like the **app might not have permission to access the network at all** (when test run it on real iOS device)

I search online for a solution and I found out that I need to set Provisioning Profile with sandbox capabilities. And later add it to my target.

I do not find in developer.apple.com -> app ID any mention of App Sandbox so my current Provisioning Profile dont include it so I can't also add it on my target(Xcode).

I tried to add to my current Provisioning Profile (app id) app sandbox but did not find any mention of it.

I added app sandbox to the .entittlemnts file.
I clean build folder and rebuild it and still app sandbox do not exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution to my issue was to allow full access in keyboard settings on my iPhone.

[image]

Comment: Note that it is required that your keyboard extension is still functional even if the user does not grant full access. https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#extensions